Cerrar el inspeccionador con js
Alguno de ustedes sabe cómo puedo cerrar la consola o el ispeccionador de Google Chrome u otro navegador web con javascript. Lo quiero usar para que no puedan inspeccionar mi página web. Ya he intentado hacer que el clic derecho no funcione con preventDefault pero si abres el inspeccionador desde otra web y abres la mía, el inspeccionador permanece activo. Cómo puedo cerrarlo con js?

Por ahora no se puede, quizás en un futuro agreguen una API o métodos para esto.

Esperemos que nunca se pueda hacer lo que quieres hacer. Desde luego yo no usuaría un navegador que permitiese este tipo de subterfugios. Si no quieres que vean lo que hace tu JS en las máquinas de los visitantes es porque a) estás tratando de hacer algo malicioso como la minería de criptomonedas, b) no quieres que te "roben" tu precioso código. Pues te digo una cosa, en el caso de que sea b) no tienes más que ver las mayores páginas web del mundo: google, facebook, etc. Todas se puede ver perfectamente lo que hacen ¿Tú crees que alguien le interesa robar el código de una página de chichinabo?

como dice @ordago, si lo haces para cuidar tu código, no hay forma, lo que puedes hacer es hacerle un minify, para que sea mas difícil de leer para la gente, pero, mucho mas rápido de leer para el navegador.
Otra cosa que puedes hacer también es evitar enviar precios o datos "sensibles" en la petición y calcularlo en el back.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

No es posible ya que el inspeccionador es una función interna del navegador.
En una extensión de Chrome se puede ver el objeto chrome, que tiene las siguientes propiedades.

loadTimes: Tiempos de carga.
csi: Datos de inicio rápido.
app: Propiedades de la aplicación.
browserAction: Botón de extensión en barra.
dom: Contenido de página.
extension: Datos de la extensión.
i18n: Los idiomas.
management: Administrar extensiones.
permissions: Ver permisos.
runtime: Funcionamiento de la extensión.
tabs: Pestañas del navegador.
windows: Ventanas del navegador.

Como se puede ver, lamentablemente no hay nada sobre el inspeccionador de elementos, ni nada que pueda manejar botones del navegador.
Solución posible en un futuro
La única forma en que esto se pueda lograr es que inventen un programa de inteligencia artificial que reconozca los objetos en imágenes mientras graba la pantalla, entre tanto, que reconozca el inspeccionador de elementos, luego el botón de cerrar, y que ese programa pueda hacer autoclick, dé un click y se cierre el inspeccionador, o que envíe señales de teclado para hacer Control + Shift + I.
Para esto es necesario pedirle al usuario que instale la aplicación de inteligencia artificial, porque de alguna manera tiene que tenerla instalada.
